# Understanding Refresh Tokens

Tags: authentication, jwt, refresh-token, express-jwt

On my journey to learn web-dev, I am now studying JWT and I can't figure out what's the point of refresh tokens. if I am going to have a long-lived token refresh tpken on the client side, I might as well not have a short-lived one. why not just have one long-lived one on rotation ?

Isn't the refresh token susceptible to theft just as much?

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't. The refresh token is something that can be used to prolong access rights, oftentimes that means that the expiry time of the access token is prolonged or a new access token can be requested.

Since the access token was sent from one direction to another, it's possible that something gained possession of said access token. That would mean that whatever gained access to it will be able to forge a request, claiming that it's a valid session and send that access token.

Now, if your access token is short-lived and your access expiry is postponed every five minutes by your app if you are using it, you are better protected if your server will not accept your access token at face value after a prolonged time, because the more time passed, the higher the probability that a listening middle-man "overheard" your token and forged a request.

So the refresh token lets the IDP know that you still use that access token. If you do not refresh that access token, then your IDP would be able to detect forgeries for their lack of refreshing themselves. Whereas, if you do not have refresh tokens, then you are less secure, lacking this kind of protection.

You can use your refresh token to get new access tokens altogether, so even if a forger possessed a formerly valid access token, that's useless by the time it expires and the use of a refresh token expires it.

The alternative you described is to use the same access token, but then you have no answer to the case when an access token is intercepted and attempted to be used by a hacker.

EDIT

Your access token is a JWT. Let's suppose you have an object of this form:

```
{
    userid: '123',
    expiration: now('+5 min'),
    refresh_token: 'somerefreshtoken'
}
```

Now, if you encrypt your JWT using a private and a public key and your client app has the public key to decode it, then instead of the readable object above, you have some random jumbled long text, such as

**dkjssFSD2FSFsadk;ajfl5a3ka=**

(just an example)

If the token above can be used to authentication for 10 hours, then, if someone steals this value, then he will be able to perform identity theft. **This is the part we already agree about**.

Now, if your access token is only valid for 5 minutes, then your refresh token being unused will be able to gather you a new short-term access token, so your old access token will not be useful for very long for hackers.

You worry about the life-cycle of the refresh token.

But the refresh token is encrypted inside the access token and a hacker will not be able to decrypt your access token to get your refresh token.

Plus, if your access token is alive for 5 minutes, then the refresh token will also expire soon, because once it requests a new access token, you will also get a new refresh token.

Therefore, the hackers will not know what your refresh token is due to the fact that it's encrypted inside the access token AND the refresh token is short-lived as well in the scenario when it changes the access token (the new access token will contain the next refresh token encrypted inside of itself in a similar manner).

If your refresh token refreshes your access token instead of changing it, then, if a hacker steals your access token and your access token is left unchanged, but prolonged by the refresh token, then your access token is a long-lived token and it is less safe than in the case when you frequently refresh it.

Your refresh token is much safer than your access token, because while your access token is a token as it is, it is the result of the encryption of your secret data, such as the refresh token and other secret data. Your hacker cannot steal your refresh token. He can only steal your access token. He would need to decrypt your access token in order to get your refresh token, which is an extremely hard, virtually impossible task if you use a good encryption algorithm and you keep your keys secure.

Comment: I am asking in the context of a simple JWT setup, not sure IDP has to be involved for the sake of answering my question. u mention that the refresh token is for when the access token is being stolen but I am asking what is preventing the hacker from stealing the refresh token just as he would steal the access token

Comment: @Ziv We speak about refresh tokens. What are those refresh tokens representing? The refreshing of the access rights over an application, by prolonging an access token or getting a new one. What does an access token represent? An identity. You are confirming your identity via the access token and you refresh the confirmation of your identity via a refresh token. Who is responsible for providing the means to confirm the identity or to validate/confirm those identities? The IDP. Therefore, we are not speaking about some random JWT, but tokens representing identities. Hence IDP is on-topic.

Comment: @Ziv the refresh token is not for the case when the token is stolen. The refresh token has the purpose to prolong access rights via extending or recreating an access token. So it's more about the flow of reconfirming an identity rather than just the case when that identity is forged. As about preventing the theft of a refresh token, since the refresh token should be inside the JWT, in an encrypted manner, the encrypted nature of JWT should protect your refresh tokens. Because even if the access token gets stolen by a hacker, he still needs to decrypt it in order to get your refresh tokens.

Comment: @Ziv so you need a hard-to decipher encryption, so even if the encrypted data ends  up in the wrong hands, they will still be unable to make anything out of its content. So, the access token is not easy to steal, but if someone manages to do so, he still will be a hard time solving the almost impossible task of decrypting it without knowing what the encryption algorithm was and what were the public and private keys used for it. So, if the hacker steals your access token, all that he can do is to put that token into some requests and pretend that he is the owner of that token.

Comment: @Ziv if your access token is long-lived, then hackers have a large window of oppoortunity of stealing your identity and causing harm to you as long as they are able to steal your encrypted access token. If the access token is short-lived, then they have a much smaller window of opportunity for causing harm to you even if they managed to steal your access token.

Comment: @LajosAprad I understand that the refresh token is not to prevent theft by itself but rather allows for the access token to be short-lived and thus prevent malicious use after theft. what I don't get is what is the point of making a short-lived token if I am going to need a long-lived refresh token that going to grant the same privileges as an access token, thus making it an access token by itself. I am going to have a long-lived token whether I use a refresh token or not.

Comment: in other words, we have a problem that long-lived tokens are susceptible to theft so we make the access token short-lived which causes a bad UI requiring repeated logins, so we use a long-lived refresh token which takes us to square on that long-lived token is susceptible to theft

Comment: @Ziv I will add an edit to this answer to provide a more comprehensive explanation to your latest doubts, because comments are ill-suited for this kind of longer explanation.

Comment: @Ziv I have provided an explanation to my answer. I hope it clarify the doubts expressed in your latest comments.

Answer (score -1):

the answer I got from Reddit:
is we use only one token we will need to make repeated calls to the server which will cause overhead